# Targeting an Array Within an Object - Observables in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

At one point I was successfully iterating over objects in an array in my Angular 2 app using observables. In my client service file I had this:

```
getByCategory(category: string) {
    const q = encodeURIComponent(category);
    return this.http.get
    (`https://api.someurl.com/${this.ver}/clients/category/${q}?apikey=${this.key}`)
        .map((response: Response) => response.json())
        .catch(this.stageErrorsHandler);
}
    stageErrorsHandler(error: Response) {
    console.error(error);
    return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error');
}
```

I then I was subscribing in my component's ngOnInit life cycle hook, like this:

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.clientService.getByCategory('consulting')
        .subscribe(resRecordsData => this.records = resRecordsData,
        responseRecordsError => this.errorMsg = responseRecordsError);
}
```

In the component, I also initiated records to be an empty array:

```
records = [];
```

And then in my view I was iterating over this array of records like this:

```
<tr *ngFor="let record of records">
```

Now the configuration of our data on the api/server has changed. Where I used to be targeting an array, that looked like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": "someid",
  }
]
```

... I need to change this to now target an array called "data", that is located WITHIN an object. It looks like this:

```
{
  "count": 1000,
  "data": [
      {
         "id": "someid",
      }
   ]
}
```

Simple question that I'm stumped over: How do I target an array WITHIN an object like this? I need to target the array within the object, because that's what *ngFor needs in order to be able to iterate over.

Comment: try let record of records.data ? or initialize records: this.records = resRecordsData.data ?

Comment: Good idea. Let me try that.

Comment: let me know if it works

Comment: @floor, that worked. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try targeting the array in records by:

```
<tr *ngFor="let record of records.data">
```

or

you could set records to data in your data retrieval:

```
this.records = resRecordsData.data
```